# how I can recreate a string

Tags: c, pic

I'm working on a project written in C, what I want to do is getting values from arguments then send to a microcontroller [pic16f887] then another code on the microcontroller with the string X (ex: x =  1234567890) I sent, I want to read the chars x[0] to x[3] and save the values in an other char D containing D = 1234. Then from x[4] to x[8] saving in char F containing F = 5678.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char a[50];
char d[50];
char c[50];

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])  {
    strcpy(a, argv[1]);
    strcpy(d, argv[2]);
    strcpy(c, argv[3]);
    strcpy(a, d);
    strcpy(a, c);

    printf("%s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

This is only a testing, see how it works.. but outputs only the 3rd argument and not all 3 at once. 
So my question is how I can combine those 3 chars to get one then from that one  reading from x[0] to x[3] save in a separate char I can handle

Comment: Can you give a code example? It might give people a better idea of what you need to solve

Comment: Try using `strcat(a,d)` and `strcat(a,c)` instead of `strcpy(a,d)` and `strcpy(a,c)`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you're trying to concatenate the first 3 arguments passed to your program.

The issue you're running into is that `strcpy` always copies into buffer `a` from the start, while you assume it is going to append to the string already stored in `a`. One way to observe that behavior is to pass command line arguments with decreasing length to your program. For example, calling it as `./a.out abcde ghij klm` will print `klmje`, and not the 3rd argument.

What you really need to do is to remember the length of what you've copied so far and start this many characters *after* the beginning of your buffer `a`. As a matter of fact, you don't even need the additional buffers besides `a`, and the buffer also doesn't need to be a global.

The following should do what you expect:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])  {
    char a[50];

    char* beginning_of_next_string = a;
    int i = 1;
    for (; i <= 3; ++i) {
        strcpy(beginning_of_next_string, argv[i]);
        beginning_of_next_strings += strlen(argv[i]);
    }

    printf("%s",a);
    return 0; 
}
```

Alternatively, since in this case the stings can't be very long, you can also use `strcat` as suggested by Vasilis in a comment to your question without much of a performance penalty. Then it reduces to

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   char a[50];

   strcpy(a, argv[1]);
   strcat(a, argv[2]);
   strcat(a, argv[3]);

   printf("%s",a);
   return 0;
```

}

Comment: Alright, this is great and there is more one question, now my A variable contains those 3 arguments. After I sent somewhere I want to read, let say the first 4 characters and save in an other array of chars , let's say B.. as I know in C a string is array of chars with the end NULL or \0 but I don't think strcpy(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3], b) will work..

Comment: @RobertErnest You can use `strncpy(a, b, 4)` for that, however if `b` has more than 4 characters then you manually have to add the '\0' to the end of `a`.